# HMM emission model with discriminative machine learning tools

Tags: machine-learning, classification, hidden-markov-models

my task is to classify an observation vector (features taken from sensors signals) to one of M states.
I can use multiclass classifiers (trees or SVM) but since these states are dependent i am looking for a model to use the dependency between the states. 
I thought of using an HHM (i am new to HMM) but from my research i mostly found the emission model to require a complete symbols set with probabilities or some generative distribution model. Both seem unfeasible.

1. How can I use the discriminative tools i know (trees , SVM) to train a suitable HMM ?
2. If it is not an appropriate model for my problem which one is ?

Note: I am Classifying human physical activity from an on-body Accelerometer. for example i may want to classify between these states: 'standing still' ' walking' & 'running'. Instead of just classifying each frame by itself i would like to treat this as a sequence. this way, for example, if i have an observation that looks like 'running' , the next observation is most likely to be 'running' too and not confused with walking which looks similar and possible but less likely.

Comment: Search specifically for HSMM (hidden Semi-Markov Models) because this variation takes into account sequences as a whole

Comment: thanks, but i am less bothered by the states transition and more by the observations issue. also any idea why i got negative rating, am i missing something obvious here ?

Comment: The negative rating goes to the fact that the question seems rather vague and not directly related to programming (which is actually true) but I happen to have experience in the topic so I decided to comment. As for your concern, have you taken a look at this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487356/hidden-markov-model-for-multiple-observed-variables

Comment: thanks , great link , CRF might be what i need.

Answer (score 0):

to my understanding, HMM must use generative emission model. A hybrid approach can use  discriminative methods to build emission probabilities as in [combined hmm & svm](http://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/media/uploads/documents/ICCV-HCI07_ValstarPantic-FINAL.pdf).